# Is it safe to update data in the database real time using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my app, for the shopping cart, I need to update the quantity values real time. Let's say someone set the quantity (but does not submit) and then close the browser. After a day or two he re-login and the updated qty should be there. For this im thinking of using `$.getJSON` to send the qty with the cart id and product id to the server so that the server can update them and send a response. Is this safe? (Im a bit new to JS and my app is on Rails)

Comment: What safety issue are you fearing? Server? Data? Anything else?

Comment: @Amit Sorry im a bit new and don't know about all the issues but, here's the issues I think might come : I add the cart id in a hidden field, if by accident it gets changes, the wrong cart might get updated (but there's nothing to gain by changing it other than ruining the site), also can someone interfere with the data coming and going to the server?

Comment: if there is no login involved can store the cart data in localStorage

Comment: @charlietfl Actually a person can buy without login and with login both.